# How to properly prefix android Classes' in javadoc generated html?

Tags: android, ant, javadoc

I am using Ant JavaDoc to generate HTML documentation for my Android App Library. I am hitting an issue where it is throwing errors "Cannot find symbol" for things such as Intent and Context which come from the Google Android SDK. I don't want to externally link to these APIs in my generated documentation but I do want them to be fully qualified in the documentation. What I mean by this is that parameters are just being specified like Context but I would like it to be generated as android.content.Context. Is there a way to achieve this with an option for Ant JavaDoc?  I can't seem to located how to do this without externally linking.

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: Could this be due to the fact that when my Ant Javadoc runs the Android jar library file is not present?  If so would this be fixed by making sure the jar file is present and referencing it via classPath?

Comment: Jes, this looks like sufficient. (Use the `-classpath` option of Javadoc.)